# Why are there two empty semicolons (;) in the function parentheses?

Tags: algorithm, function, syntax, pseudocode

So I was working on functions in my algorithm class when I saw this pseudocode:
`function TreeVal(;;T)`
It's a recursive function to evaluate an expression tree. I was wondering why the two empty semicolons are there and can't we just omit them.
Thank you in advance.
**Edit:** Pseudocode added

```
function treeVal(T;;);  
    if T.operator = null then Return(T.val)
    else Return(eval(T.operator, treeVal(T.left), treeVal(T.right)))
```

**eval**(operator,x,y) is a function to evaluate (x operator y)

Comment: Hi can you please share the complete code

Comment: At a guess (since you have not posted the pseudocode) this is a function with three parameters, but on this call the first two parameters are not passed.  My guess might be wrong of course.